# iOS 7 Phonegap FileTransfer Upload Image

Tags: image, cordova, upload, ios7

i have built an app using phonegap.
This app functions well in Android, and also in iOS, but only up to iOS 7.
I don't know why, but when i try to upload an image via Phonegap FileTransfer method, the image is not uploaded.

Have you already faced this issue?
How can I fix it?
I think that probably it's a phonegap bug, that has not yet been detected.

Can You help me please?

Thank you in advance!

That is my function that uploads an image:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) 
      {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";

            if(isJumperTagPost)
            {

                img=original_img.src;
            }
            else
            {
                img=jQuery("#image_att").attr('src');
            }

            temp=img.substr(img.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            check_jpg=temp.indexOf(".jpg");
            if(check_jpg==-1)
            {
                options.fileName=img.substr(img.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+".jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                options.fileName=img.substr(img.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            }
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";


            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(img,"http://www.myurl.com", win, fail,options);
        }
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on and help if you don't post any code. Can you also describe what exactly isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? I built an app that is currently in the store that uses FileTransfer to upload images to a server and it works just fine on iOS 7.

Comment: Ok, I have posted my function!

Comment: hello, i face same problem. you get solution for iOS .?